# Use of aggregate with self join

Tags: mysql

I have roughly following MySQL table structure (`listings`):

| id | state | county | area | price_per_acre | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

All column names are self explanatory.

I want to get all `listings` that have +/-50% area of one specific listing (with specific `id`), have status 1 or 2 and have the same `state` and `county` as that specific listing.

The query for that I have built is:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.price_per_acre 
FROM
    listings t1
    JOIN listings t2 ON t1.area >= t2.area * 0.5 
    AND t1.area <= t2.area * 1.5 
    AND t1.STATUS IN ( 1, 2 ) 
    AND t1.state = t2.state 
    AND t1.county = t2.county 
WHERE
    t2.id = 1731961;
```

Now I want to add another clause to `WHERE` using aggregate function, to further filter entries which have `price_per_acre` greater than average `price_per_acre` from the same set (by the same set I mean the results of the above query), so I try something like:

```sql
SELECT
    `t1`.`id`,
    `t1`.`price_per_acre` 
FROM
    `listings` AS `t1`
    JOIN `listings` AS `t2` ON (
        `t1`.`area` >= `t2`.`area` * 0.5 
        AND `t1`.`area` <= `t2`.`area` * 1.5 
        AND `t1`.`status` IN ( 1, 2 ) 
        AND `t1`.`state` = `t2`.`state` 
        AND `t1`.`county` = `t2`.`county` 
    ) 
WHERE
    `t2`.`id` = 1731961 
    AND `t1`.`price_per_acre` > AVG( `t1`.`price_per_acre` );
```

But I get `invalid use of group function` error.

P.S. I know that I need to use `GROUP BY` for the aggregate to work in condition, but I'm not sure by what or how to group to get the desired results. I have even tried to build another self join to the same result set but without success.

**UPDATE**
I got following query which technically does what I need, but I simply built another full join to itself (and by 'itself' I mean the full first join to itself). Is there any better way to do that (more readable or performant)?

```
SELECT
    `t1`.`price_per_acre`, `t3`.`avg`
FROM
    `listings` AS `t1`
    JOIN `listings` AS `t2` ON (
        `t1`.`area` >= `t2`.`area` * 0.5
        AND `t1`.`area` <= `t2`.`area` * 1.5
        AND `t1`.`status` IN (1, 2)
        AND `t1`.`state` = `t2`.`state`
        AND `t1`.`county` = `t2`.`county`
        AND `t2`.`id` = 1731961
    )
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            AVG(`t1`.`price_per_acre`) AS `avg`
        FROM `listings` AS `t1`
        JOIN `listings` AS `t2` ON (
            `t1`.`area` >= `t2`.`area` * 0.5
            AND `t1`.`area` <= `t2`.`area` * 1.5
            AND `t1`.`status` IN (1, 2)
            AND `t1`.`state` = `t2`.`state`
            AND `t1`.`county` = `t2`.`county`
            AND `t2`.`id` = 1731961
        )
    ) AS `t3` ON (`t1`.`price_per_acre` > `t3`.`avg`);
```

[Here's a fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=96e50f421fe22966b0a5b34759490fde)

Comment: I was thinking of something along the line of what you've updated then I notice something, didn't you say that `id` entries are unique? So when you do `t2.id = 1731961` in the query for `AVG(t1.price_per_acre)` in the subquery won't it just return the same value as `t1.price_per_acre` on the outer query? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1ae867744bfb6cb7c97ad4c3fbe3e814

Comment: @FaNo_FN Nope, it actually works as I'm averaging the result of the join query (in subquery). Your fiddle shows incorrect result as you only have 1 row, I've updated the fiddle, check here (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=96e50f421fe22966b0a5b34759490fde). The only problem is I think that this query can at least rewritten to be more readable (the performance is ok with the indexes I have).

Comment: It seems like you don't need to repeat the join query https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=17d892a4dde1fe21b75dda387c2a80d8

Answer (score 0):

This

```
AND `t1`.`price_per_acre` > AVG(`t1`.`price_per_acre`);
```

is not acceptable. To get `AVG()` you'll need a `GROUP BY` and you're trying to compare each `t1`.`price_per_acre` that the query returns with a single `AVG()` which has not been generated yet. Probably the quickest way to resolve this is by doing another `JOIN` on your existing query with a sub-query that contains `AVG()` value for each `id`. Try this:

```
SELECT `t1`.`id`, `t1`.`price_per_acre`
FROM `listings` AS `t1`
JOIN `listings` AS `t2` ON (`t1`.`area` >= `t2`.`area` * 0.5 AND `t1`.`area` <= `t2`.`area` * 1.5 AND `t1`.`status` IN (1, 2) AND `t1`.`state` = `t2`.`state` AND `t1`.`county` = `t2`.`county`)
CROSS JOIN 
   (SELECT AVG(`price_per_acre`) AS AVG_ppa FROM `listing`) t3
WHERE `t2`.`id` = 1731961 AND `t1`.`price_per_acre` > `t3`.`AVG_ppa`;
```

Comment: First of all I get error with your code and second I'm not sure how this gonna work. Your 3rd join subquery has `AVG(t1.price_per_acre)` which is wrong, as `t1` is not available during that subquery. If you meant just `AVG(price_per_acre)` then it will just output `price_per_acre` as you are grouping just with `id` which is unique for each entry.
I was also thinking something similar, but not sure how to correctly construct third join.

Comment: Oh yes my mistake, `t1` shouldn't be in the subquery. I was assuming that the entry wasn't unique. If that's the case, maybe you need the third join to be a `CROSS JOIN`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: After re-reading your question, I can't help to think that the query I suggest still won't cut it. I already get the general idea but currently I'm on mobile so I'm not able to test. I'll get back to you once I'm on my computer.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Not sure cross join will work here. Please check my update, I technically got what I need, but I just joined again to itself (fully) and I'm not sure that it's readable. Maybe you can recommend any better way?